# Mark nodejs error as expected in New Relic

Tags: node.js, newrelic

Is there a way to mark an error as expected in new relic with nodejs? For example, if it's ruby, we could do: `notice_error(error, expected: true)`(https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/api-guides/sending-handled-errors-new-relic). Is there an equivalent with nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, *currently there's no way* to specify that you notice expected error in Node.

The easiest workaround that brings almost the same capabilities is to create and to throw dedicated error class for expected errors (for instance, `NewRelicExpectedError`).
Then you can specify ignored error classes in New Relic UI - check [Server-side agent configuration article](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/manage-apm-agents/configuration/server-side-agent-configuration) to understand how to find necessary settings.

Example code:

```js
class NewRelicExpectedError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}

// ...

if (/* 'error is expected' condition */) {
  throw new NewRelicExpectedError('error message');
}
```

However, one is able to configure New Relic for particular app only in restricted way from UI.
So consider utilizing local config file that allows to specify expected error messages along with error classes, as well as provides much more rich capabilities list in general than UI does.
For reference, take a look at [this page](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/nodejs-agent-configuration), where it is explained how to fine-tune it. Note: try searching 'expected_messages' within a page to find info about expected errors. Looks like New Relic documentation doesn't support deep links;(

Comment: @wtesfsd123 does this answer your question?